# Taking input for int64_t

Tags: c, io

Currently I am working on program where input is in the range 10^-6<=x<=10^6,and hence I want to use int64_t, but can't figure out how to take input using it.Please help!!

Comment: From where? File, console? Network?

Comment: `scanf` with the right specifier?

Comment: There seems to be something missing from the question, since `10^-6` needs some sort of transformation before it can be represented as a `int`

Comment: `10^-6` is `0.000001` and not an integer.  Please explain coding goals.

Answer (score 7):

The portable way is to use `<inttypes.h>` and do

`scanf("%" SCNd64, &your_variable)`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    int64_t x;
    scanf("%lld", &x);
    printf("ans is %lld", x);
```

Comment: There is no guarantee that `int64_t` is the same as `long long`, and you get undefined behavior if that's not the case. Use the format in Jabberwock's answer instead.